# Difference between WebDAV and socket.io (which one is better ?)

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webdav

Here is my story :

I have a busy server (too much queries every minute), and I'm trying to upload images on that server, the problem is I don't know what to use to have good performance.

Can someone tell me the differences in performance between :

- uploading a file using WebDAV protocol.
- uploading a file using WebSocket Protocol  (socket.io).

which method is `faster + consumes less resources + better`.

Can you tell me for example what method `YouTube` is using for uploads ?

Thanks all.

Comment: If you have your own server and client then you may create your own protocol over HTTP for example.

Comment: WebDAV is just set of methods to work with files over HTTP and it is not cost-saving. To upload a file through WebDAV you need at least two queries - HEAD (or PROPFIND) to ensure the file is not exists on the path with such name and PUT request (sometimes POST).

Comment: But you may send PUT request only and server should return some error for example 412 Precondition Failed if such file name is busy.

Comment: But still not enough information provided. Can you change the server? Why it is busy? What kind of client (browser, desktop, mobile)? How images uploaded now?

Comment: Thx so much, so if WebDAV is not cost-saving thats mean that WebSocket Protocol offers better performance ? cause there is an Ericsson Labs comparison showing that WebSocket is much faster. here is the video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z897fkPn7Rw)

Comment: Why do you think that current upload mechanism is bad? You need to do more investigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Websocket can save resources if the socket is re-used for multiple communications requests. But if you used it to facillitate single uploads there would be no difference between it and a normal HTTP PUT.

Thats because creating a websocket connection goes through the same steps as initiating a normal HTTP connection, but then changes mode at the end so the connection is ready and waiting for transfers. So if a user was to do 10 uploads using a websocket connection there is potentially an advantage because there would only be one handshake, while for normal HTTP PUT there would be 10 handshakes.

But to do websocket uploads you will need to "roll your own" because there is no standard file upload semantics as part of the websocket standard, as there is with HTTP. And that means the potential for bugs and inefficiencies.

So to answer which approach is "better" I think the performance gain from using websockets for file upload would be small, perhaps not measurable, but doing so would introduce the risk of bugs and inefficiencies.

Comment: Thx man, I wanna give u +1 but I need 15 reputation, and I got only 2, thx again